# JSON exclude may when field is Null

Tags: apex, json, serialization

In my code below how can I have it exclude one of the field maps if the value in the correspondence field is Null.  So in this example if Field 3 is Null I do not want this included in the output field maps.
I plan to use this to to Post to Slack so both the format and order need to be exact.

```
String field1 = '*Field 1* Value';
String field2 = '*Field 2* Value';
String field3 = '';


Map<String, Object> FieldMap1 = new Map<String, Object> {
        'type' => 'mrkdwn',
        'text' => field1
        };
        
Map<String, Object> FieldMap2 = new Map<String, Object> {
        'type' => 'mrkdwn',
        'text' => field2
        };


Map<String, Object> FieldMap3 = new Map<String, Object> {
        'type' => 'mrkdwn',
        'text' => field3
        };
    
System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(FieldMap3, true));

String output = JSON.serializePretty(
  new Map<String, Object> {
    'fields' => new Object[] { 
         FieldMap1,
         FieldMap2,
         FieldMap3
    },
   'type' => 'section'
  }
);

System.debug(output);
```

Answer (score 3):

You set field3 to empty string, not `null`. These are quite different values in JSON (and Apex). Also you only suppressed nulls in your first serialise, not both.

Make sure you really have null values and ensure you pass `suppressApexObjectNulls` as `true` every time (see the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_Json.htm)).

If you need to exclude empty strings as well, either ensure these don't get into the Map while building it or apply a post process to the Map (the latter could be difficult to do depending on how it is built).

Now, the next issue is that your FieldMap3 is added to your array regardless as to whether the `text` value is not null (or empty/blank). To resolve this you should again either ensure to avoid adding it during `Map` building or strip it out in a post process.

In both cases it is far easier to handle during build, but here is a half-way-house that lets you still generate the field map entries and post-filters them based on the `text` property value:

```
String output = JSON.serializePretty(
  new Map<String, Object> {
    'fields' => filterFieldMaps(new Object[] { 
         FieldMap1,
         FieldMap2,
         FieldMap3
    }),
   'type' => 'section'
  }
);

...

private Object[] filterFieldMaps(Object[] fieldMaps) {
  Object[] result = new Object[0];

  for (Object entry : fieldMaps) {
    Map<String, Object> fieldMap = (Map<String, Object>) entry;

    String text = (String) fieldMap.get('text');

    if (String.isNotBlank(text)) {
      result.add(entry);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Clearly the method needs to belong to a class of some form.